# Power Shell: Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I want to create a new resource group in azure via power shell with the command:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroup - Name name -Location "WesternEurope"
```

then I get the error message:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroup : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login."

But I am already logged in with "Login-AzureRmAccount" and entered my Azure credentials.

## Edit:

I got it. In this page, there are two commands to install azure modules for powershell.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/

Install the Azure Resource Manager modules from the PowerShell Gallery

```
Install-Module AzureRM
```

Install the Azure Service Management module from the PowerShell Gallery

```
Install-Module Azure
```

With the AzureRm modules it worked.

Comment: Please use `Get-AzureRmSubscription` to check if your account has a subscription id or not.

Comment: My Account has a subscription, when i use Login-AzureRmAccount i get displayed the current subscription id used.

Answer (score 1):

It might be unrelated, but WesternEurope is not a valid value for Location. Either WestEurope or "West Europe" would do.

It seems far-fetched, but does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, as it worked I got that error at the next time. "westeurope" is correct.

Comment: where's the list of valid region strings?

Comment: Get-AzureRmLocation | Select -ExpandProperty Location